# How to properly autolayout subviews of custom tableviewcell programatically [iOS9]

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I created own subclass of UITableViewCell. There are a few subviews (2x imageview, 2x UILabel). I did everything programatically also constraints but on some cells autolayout isn't computed properly and I don't know why. And here is [screenshot](https://upx.cz/BIV) of my tableview with mentioned issue.

Thanks for any advice.

Here is source of my cell

```
//menu list cell
class TableMenuViewCell:  UITableViewCell{

    var stripe:UIView?
    var separatorTop:UIView?
    var separatorBottom:UIView?
    var imageBox:UIView?
    var img:UIImageView?
    var dateBox:UIImageView?
    var date:UILabel?
    var label:UILabel?
    var desc:UILabel?
    var foreground:UIView?
    var multiplier:CGFloat = 1
    var didSetupConstraints:Bool = false

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.backgroundColor = Constants.grayColor

        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad {
            multiplier = 1.3
        }

        //stripe
        stripe = UIView()
        stripe!.backgroundColor = Constants.light2GrayColor
        stripe!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(stripe!)

        //image box
        imageBox = UIView()
        imageBox!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        imageBox!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(imageBox!)

        //image view
        img = UIImageView()
        img!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        img!.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
        img!.clipsToBounds = true;
        img!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = false
        imageBox!.addSubview(img!)

        //constraints
        imageBox!.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[img]-0-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["img" : img! ]))
        imageBox!.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[img]-0-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["img" : img! ]))

        //label
        label = UILabel()
        label!.numberOfLines = 0
        label!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        label!.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        label!.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
        label!.font = UIFont(name: Constants.FONT_MEDIUM, size: Constants.MENU_LABEL_FONT_SIZE * multiplier)
        label!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(label!)
        label!.sizeToFit()

        //desc
        desc = UILabel()
        desc!.numberOfLines = 0
        desc!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        desc!.textColor = Constants.turquoiseColor
        desc!.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
        desc!.font = UIFont(name: Constants.FONT_THIN, size: Constants.MENU_DESC_FONT_SIZE * multiplier)
        desc!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(desc!)
        desc!.sizeToFit()

        //separator top
        separatorTop = UIView()
        separatorTop!.backgroundColor = Constants.lightGrayColor
        separatorTop!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(separatorTop!)

        //separator bottom
        separatorBottom = UIView()
        separatorBottom!.backgroundColor = Constants.lightGrayColor
        separatorBottom!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(separatorBottom!)

        //foreground
        foreground = UIView()
        foreground!.backgroundColor = Constants.light2GrayHoverColor
        foreground!.alpha = 0.5
        foreground!.opaque = false

        self.selectedBackgroundView = foreground!

    }

    //set layout
    func setLayout(rowIndex : Int){

        if didSetupConstraints{
            return
        }
        else{
            didSetupConstraints = true
        }


        let views:[String:AnyObject] = ["stripe" : stripe!, "imageBox" : imageBox!, "label" : label!, "desc" : desc!, "separatorTop" : separatorTop!, "separatorBottom" : separatorBottom!]

        let metrics:[String:AnyObject] = ["hMargin" : Constants.HORIZONTAL_MARGIN, "vMargin" : Constants.VERTICAL_MARGIN, "stripeWidth" : Constants.STRIPE_WIDTH, "separatorHeight" : Constants.SEPARATOR_HEIGHT]

        var constraintsArr:[NSLayoutConstraint] = []

        //horizontal constraints
        constraintsArr.appendContentsOf( NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[separatorTop]-0-|", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views) )

        constraintsArr.appendContentsOf( NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[separatorBottom]-0-|", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views) )

        constraintsArr.appendContentsOf( NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[stripe(==stripeWidth)]-(hMargin)-[imageBox]-(hMargin)-[label]-0-|", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views) )

        constraintsArr.appendContentsOf( NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[stripe(==stripeWidth)]-(hMargin)-[imageBox]-(hMargin)-[desc]-0-|", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views) )

        constraintsArr.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageBox!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: self.bounds.height - 4*Constants.VERTICAL_MARGIN))

        //vertical constraints
        constraintsArr.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: stripe!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: self.bounds.height))

        constraintsArr.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: stripe!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: separatorTop!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

        constraintsArr.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: stripe!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: separatorBottom!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

        constraintsArr.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageBox!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

        constraintsArr.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageBox!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: self.bounds.height - 4*Constants.VERTICAL_MARGIN))

        if desc!.text!.isEmpty {

            constraintsArr.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

        }else{

            constraintsArr.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterYWithinMargins, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterYWithinMargins, multiplier: 1, constant: -label!.bounds.height*0.5))

            constraintsArr.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: desc!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TopMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: label!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: Constants.VERTICAL_MARGIN + Constants.VERTICAL_MARGIN * multiplier ))

        }

        constraintsArr.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: separatorTop!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: rowIndex != 0 ? 0 : Constants.SEPARATOR_HEIGHT))

        constraintsArr.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: separatorBottom!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: Constants.SEPARATOR_HEIGHT))


        self.addConstraints(constraintsArr)
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        imageView!.image = nil
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Source of Table view controller

```
    import UIKit

class MenuViewController: UITableViewController {

    var cellHeight:CGFloat = 50

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        initTableView()

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func initTableView(){

        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
        tableView.backgroundColor = Constants.grayColor
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = cellHeight
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.registerClass(TableMenuViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(TableMenuViewCell))

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0.001
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad {
            return cellHeight * 1.2
        }
        return cellHeight
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 16
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier( NSStringFromClass(TableMenuViewCell), forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableMenuViewCell


        //stripe
        cell.stripe!.backgroundColor = Constants.turquoiseColor

        //image
        cell.img!.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")
        cell.img!.sizeToFit()

        //image box
        cell.imageBox!.sizeToFit()

        //label
        cell.label!.text = "Main Label"
        cell.label!.sizeToFit()

        //desc
        cell.desc!.text = "Description Text"
        cell.desc!.sizeToFit()

        cell.setLayout(indexPath.row)
        cell.setNeedsLayout()
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()

        return cell
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you create a table cell with .xib / prototype cell in storyboard , then set your auto layout constraints ? In this format we don't know how constraints are applying on objects.

Comment: *Question:* could you please share the mock up of what layout and under what circumstances you would like to achieve. From your screenshot I see two types of layout: 1. "image+two labels" layout and 2. "image+one labels" layout. *Suggestion:* use two `UITableViewCell`'s subclasses for each layout, to simplify things with Autolayout. Autolayout is powerful but very sensitive instrument, it requires precise tuning, otherwise you are in big trouble, trying to solve layout conflicts.

Comment: @Bharath Vankireddy Hi, for better understanding of my problem I added link to screenshot of my table view. And why I don't use storyboards? Because I do everything programatically, and after that is more easier for me to reuse views and controllers in other apps. But I know that my approach is more time consuming for the fist time.

Comment: @maho125 Its taking some time to understand the constraints what you added on your view. will check and let you know.

Comment: @Eugene Dubinin Yes you're right there are 2 types of layouts. (with one label and with 2 labels). Here is [proper mocup ](https://upx.cz/BI8)  and here is [mocup with bad layout ](https://upx.cz/BIS)

Comment: @maho125 OK, so it is definitely would be more easy to use two `UITableViewCell`'s subclasses. Just one cell for two layouts would either require a constraint(s) removing at the runtime, or somehow complicated priority setup.

Comment: @Eugene Dubinin ok, I'll try to use two different subclasses. Thanks

Comment: @Joe Hallenbeck Thanks for revision of question tags. It was my mistake.

Comment: @Eugene Dubinin So your approach works for me. I create two subclasses of UITableViewCell one for cell with one label and second for cell with two label. And also I changed in my code self for self.contentView based on apple docs. And it works. Thanks man.

Comment: @maho125 glad to hear this! happy coding!